# grunt - build eot, woff, ttf and svg

Tags: svg, build, gruntjs, truetype, eot

I've build my javascript project using grunt. It's working fine for javascript and css files. Please find below one of the classes of my css.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'demo_icons';
  src: url('../font/demo_icons.eot?79280179');
  src: url('../font/demo_icons.eot?79280179#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../font/demo_icons.woff?79280179') format('woff'),
       url('../font/demo_icons.ttf?79280179') format('truetype'),
       url('../font/demo_icons.svg?79280179#demo_icons') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

I've all these files in `font` directory.
Currently I need to provide this icons in build version.
I don't want to use this icon files in my build version. Is there anyway to integrate it in css ???

**How do I process eot, woff, ttf and svg in grunt build ???**

Answer (score 0):

Convert each file's data to base64 and embed it directly in the CSS via a [data uri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

```
src url('data:[<MIME-type>];base64,<data>')
```

MIME-type would be image/svg+xml for the SVG font for instance.